# How to invoke navigation on Google maps using Siri?

Tags: iphone, siri, maps, google-maps, navigation

At the risk of getting a big NO,

Is there a way to use SIRI to invoke navigation on Google maps as opposed to the default Apple maps?

I have tried "Navigate to Chicago using Google maps", but Siri just treated "Chicago using Google maps" as the location itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the closest and best bet I happened to find on Google:

Append "via transit" to the end of the voice command and Siri brings up a bunch of transport apps. You can click route on Google Maps and you should be on your way.

http://jailbreak-untethered.com/how-to-use-siri-and-google-maps-for-directions-without-jailbreaking-video/

Pretty Slick!!!

Answer (score 10):

### Yes you can

Simply append "via transit" to your Siri query.
Ie: Directions to Miami Beach, Florida via Transit.

Siri will determine your target location, and will give you a choice of transit apps. Tap Google Maps and you'll be on your way.

It appears these words also work:

- by transit
- using transit
- via transit

Comment: Yes. This works very well!

Comment: I created a 3rd party app ("Drive Mode") that supports this without needing Siri (no need to jailbreak). Check it out: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drive-mode/id601717235?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Not any more, it seems. Appending "via transit" appears to cause Siri to think that you want to use public transport (iPad 4,IOS10).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, 3rd party Siri integration is something that hasn't been available to developers (yet). For example, it would be really nice to say, "Start a running activity with RunKeeper," and have it start a running activity.

The closest thing to this is to simply say "Open Google Maps." I know it may seem a little lacking, but that is all we get right now.

Comment: Ha Thanks! Guess I just needed to hear a NO. Anyways here is something I found on Google. 

http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/open-google-maps-directions-with-siri-or-launch-center-pro/

Well its not really what I was looking for but just thought it relavant to the thread.

Comment: Pretty neat. Looks very creative. I am really hoping Apple releases an API for Siri soon. I know there is a lot to it, but I also know developers would use it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect an API for quite some time. There of course is a private API - but the best [analysis on why it won't be open any time soon comes from Kontra](http://counternotions.com/2012/11/12/siri-future/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it **is** possible to invoke Google maps using Siri if you're running iOS 5 on your iPhone 4S. Sadly, one can't easily downgrade, so if you're already using iOS 6, you're out of luck for now.

Comment: Ooh - good edge case - some might still be on iOS 5.

Comment: I've revived an old iPhone running iOS 5, but it's not a 4S so no Siri.

Comment: However, this is tagged iPhone-5, so...

Comment: Information needed to answer a question should be contained in the question, not in tags. Tags are for filtering. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Update: if you're using iOS 8 you can now just tell siri " driving directions to,,, using Google maps". Works most of time.